# RAII object for releasing pointer with arbitrary function

Tags: c++, c++11, template, pointers, raii

The following class is a sort of "smart pointer" that can be used for automatically releasing pointers:

```
template <class Type>
class Releaser {
 public:
  Releaser(std::function<void(Type *)> function = [](Type *value) {
    value->Release();
  });
  ~Releaser();
  Type *operator->();
  Type &operator*();
  Type *get();
  Type **fill();

 private:
  Type *value_ = nullptr;
  std::function<void(Type *)> function_;
};

template <class Type>
Releaser<Type>::Releaser(std::function<void(Type *)> function)
    : function_(function) {}

template <class Type>
Releaser<Type>::~Releaser() {
  if (value_) function_(value_);
}

template <class Type>
Type *Releaser<Type>::operator->() {
  return value_;
}

template <class Type>
Type &Releaser<Type>::operator*() {
  return *value_;
}

template <class Type>
Type *Releaser<Type>::get() {
  return value_;
}

template <class Type>
Type **Releaser<Type>::fill() {
  return &value_;
}
```

It can be used for example like this:

```
Releaser<IMFAttributes> attributes;
auto status = MFCreateAttributes(attributes.fill(), 1);
```

where `MFCreateAttributes` has the following signature:

```
MFCreateAttributes(IMFAttributes** ppMFAttributes, unsigned int cInitialSize);
```

Do you see any way to improve this (e.g by getting rid of the std::function), or make it safer?

Comment: `unique_ptr` supports custom deleters. Though the deleter type will leak into the template arguments (which can be alleviated using a typedef).

Comment: unique_ptr doesn't work because of the missing "fill" functionality. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403750/initializing-a-stdunique-ptr-by-passing-the-address-of-the-pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr` has capability for custom deleters.

Besides that assuming you are doing this to deal with COM objects then you can use [ComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244983.aspx) and its `GetAddressOf`

---

If you define a destructor you should also define (or disallow in this case) the copy construct and copy assign. Failure to do so will result in dangling pointers and double frees:

```
Releaser<IMFAttributes> attributes;
auto status = MFCreateAttributes(attributes.fill(), 1);
{
    Releaser<IMFAttributes> att = attributes;
} // att gets cleaned up

//attributes contains a dangling pointer
```

Comment: Thenks, very useful input! unique_ptr doesn't work because of the missing `GetAddressOf` function. I didn't know `ComPtr`, but this works quite well for cases where only a simple `Release` is needed, however not for custom release functions (for example if `value_->Shutdown()` has to be called instead of `value_->Release())`. Preventing a copy constructor is a very good point though. Also, I ended up adding an `assert(value != nullptr)` in the fill function, to avoid overriding a non-released pointer.